# python tensorflow windows exception

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip

Many thanks for reading this.
I tried searching but could not find an answer to this.
I have been trying to install tensorflow using pip on Windows 8.1 using python 3.5.2. I get this error.

```
C:\Users\Default.HP>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

Collecting tensorflow  
  Using cached tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl  
Collecting numpy>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow)  
  Using cached numpy-1.12.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl  
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow)  
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Collecting protobuf>=3.1.0 (from tensorflow)  
  Using cached protobuf-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow)  
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow)  
  Using cached setuptools-34.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Collecting appdirs>=1.4.0 (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow)  
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Collecting packaging>=16.8 (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow)  
  Using cached packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Collecting pyparsing (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorf
low)  
  Using cached pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Installing collected packages: numpy, six, appdirs, pyparsing, packaging, setupt
ools, protobuf, wheel, tensorflow  
Exception:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 20
9, in main  
    status = self.run(options, args)  
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", li
ne 317, in run prefix=options.prefix_path,  
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 73
2, in install  
    **kwargs  
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
e 835, in install  
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)  
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
e 1030, in move_wheel_files isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 344, in
move_wheel_files  
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)  
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 315, in
clobber  
    ensure_dir(destdir)  
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line
 83, in ensure_dir  
    os.makedirs(path)  
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\os.py", line 241, in makedirs  
    mkdir(name, mode)  
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python35\\Li
b\\site-packages\\numpy'  
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.  
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.
```

When trying to upgrade pip, I then get this error

```
C:\Users\Default.HP>python -m pip install --upgrade pip  

Collecting pip  
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Installing collected packages: pip  
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1  
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.1:  
Exception:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 538, in move  
    os.rename(src, real_dst)  
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python35\\li
b\\site-packages\\pip-8.1.1.dist-info\\description.rst' -> 'C:\\Users\\Default.H
P\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-0fd55_is-uninstall\\program files\\python35\\lib\\s
ite-packages\\pip-8.1.1.dist-info\\description.rst'  

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 20
9, in main  
    status = self.run(options, args)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", li
ne 317, in run  
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 72
6, in install  
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
e 746, in uninstall  
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", l
ine 115, in remove  
    renames(path, new_path)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line
 267, in renames  
    shutil.move(old, new)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 553, in move
    os.unlink(src)  
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python35\\li
b\\site-packages\\pip-8.1.1.dist-info\\description.rst'  
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.  
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.
```

How can this be solved?

Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like the `pip` and `numpy` upgrades are failing because they were installed by an Administrator user. You could try running the same commands in an [administrator command prompt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx) or alternatively creating a virtualenv as the current user and installing it there.

Comment: Many thanks. This works great. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This permission error arises when `pip` (running as a non-Administrator user) tries to upgrade a package that was installed by an Administrator user. There are two main workarounds:

1. Run the upgrade command using an [Administrator command prompt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx).
2. Install TensorFlow into a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) owned by the non-Administrator user.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with my internet connection. 
Had lots of slide interruptions which would stop the process and trow those Exceptions.

So summary, Run the terminal as admin and make sure you have no network interruption during the download process.